# .htaccess add ?timestamp or ?random numbers after .html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to add after those static pages 1.html  2.html 3.html ...100.html  a string with random numbers or timestamp so if example my site is

```
example.com/1.html
```

to be

```
example.com/1.html?201507101510
```

i have try this code but no sucess

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}?%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR} [L,R=302,NE]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working fine for me

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ /$1.html?%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR} [L,R=302,NE]
```

Redirects

```
http://example.com/1.html
```

to

```
http://example.com/1.html?TimeStamp
```

Comment: i get this result  http://example.com.com/home/ultra/www/public/example/3.html?2015071018